# Cannot trace why my WAMP server is redirecting to a folder even after reinstallation?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp, wampserver

I previously had installed **WAMP server** on my computer. In that installation, I **intentionally made to redirect** to a folder `/folderA/` from the **root directory** `/`.

That is, if someone enters `http://myip/`, then he/she will get redirected to `http://myip/folderA/`.

However, I cannot remember exactly how I **made that redirection** *i.e.* whether in the apache `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` or else where.

Even after **complete deletion** of all the files in the folder `C:\wamp` except the `c:\wamp\www\` folder, and **reinstallation of WAMP server**, the redirection still happens.

I am totally confused here, hunting for the culprit for hours.

I **indeed have** a `.htaccess` file in the folder `c:\wamp\www\`  but only has the **following content**

```
Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

<Files ~ "^(.*)\.(tpl|txt)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BackWeb [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bandit [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BatchFTP [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BecomeBot [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [NC]
# # etc..
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [NC]
# RewriteRule . abuse.txt [L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example-cookie=true
# RewriteRule .* /err/401.ph

# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !99.99.99.99
# RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_URI} !+
```

What are the **possibilities for this annoyance** that I might have overlooked during the **whole process of reinstallation**?

**UPDATE**

Okay. Till now, I  managed to find that the redirection happens only when using `http://myip` and `localhost` but not when using `127.0.0.1`!!!

Comment: your code looks incomplete. but did you try and clear your browser cache?

Comment: @PanamaJack: Thanks! How silly! It worked.